# How 'discontinuous' can a continuous function over the rationals $\mathbb Q$ be?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined as:

$$
 f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      -1 & \text{if } x < \sqrt{2} 
    \\
       1 & \text{if } x > \sqrt{2}
   \end{cases}
$$

This function has a jump in the colloquial sense, but it is continuous when the rationals $\mathbb Q$ are equipped with the standard topology: every rational number $q$ has a small open neighborhood that is either stricly below $\sqrt 2$ or strictly above it.

I am trying to make sense of this.

1. How 'discontinuous' such a continuous function can be. Apparently, one can pick an increasing sequence of irrational numbers and then construct a continuous function with countably many jumps, so the jumps are at least countable.
2. From the broader perspective of general topology, what is the relevant property of the topological space $\mathbb Q$ here?

Comment: Even the inclusion $\Bbb Q\hookrightarrow\Bbb R$ is continuous but it is unimaginably "jumpy"

Comment: The humble floor function $x\mapsto \lfloor x+\sqrt 2\rfloor$ has countably infinite jumps.

Comment: One thing to say about point 2 is that $\mathbb{Q}$ is totally disconnected, so that in some sense every point is its own little island topologically.

Comment: CharlesHudgins: wouldn't that mean that I can define a continuous function on each of these islands separately, and it is always continuous? In other words, every function on $\mathbb Q$ is continuous, in that interpretation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topology of $\mathbb{Q}$ is called "totally disconnected": the connected components are singletons (careful: beginners often think this means the space is discrete, which is obviously not the case with $\mathbb{Q}$).

The fact that a continuous function should not have a "jump" is an idea that comes from the intuition of a connected space (since we learn analysis and topology starting from real intervals), but when spaces are not connected, jumps are allowed. And $\mathbb{Q}$ is as little connected as possible, so you can jump a lot.

Comment: So, unlike in the discrete topology, the connected components are not necessarily open.

Comment: Indeed, connected components are always closed, but are only open in rather simple cases.

Comment: Thank you. If you can, please comment on this: $\mathbb Q$ can apparently be broken up further and further into clopen sets, but there are no "smallest" non-empty clopen sets. In particular, $\mathbb Q$ is **not** the direct sum/disjoint union of its connected components (which is puzzling). The latter would actually be the discrete topology.

Answer (score 0):

It'll always be at least a little bit continuous.

For any continuous $f:\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{R}$ there is $p\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ such that $f$ extends continuously to $\mathbb{Q}\cup \{p\}$. This is because we can extend $f$ to a $G_\delta$ subset of $\mathbb{R}$, but $\mathbb{Q}$ is not $G_\delta$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Above reasoning is related to a theorem of Lavrentieff about extending homeomorphisms between subsets of complete metric spaces to homeomorphisms of $G_\delta$ sets.

On the other spectrum, there is a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}$ which can't be extended by any rational point to a continuous function.

So in some sense, such function will be more continuous than a function on irrationals can be.