# Fixed Point Property of Rationals

Tags: rational-numbers, fixed-points

Does the space $X = [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ have a fixed point property (FPP)? i.e. can we find a continuous function, $f: [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ without a fixed point?

(My version of the answer: Since this set of rationals can be considered homeomorphic to a countable metric space without isolated points (*is this correct?*), and since this space has no FPP, neither does $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$)

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: Go back and make sure you fully understand continuous maps, discrete spaces, and the topology of $\Bbb Q$  before you address this problem specifically. Go all the way back to the basic definitions and show that:

1. $Q$ is not discrete.
2. $Q\cap[0,1]$ is not discrete
3. $\Bbb Z$ is discrete
4. If $X$ is discrete, every map $f:X\to X$ is continuous
5. A metric space without isolated points is not discrete
6. A finite discrete space with more than one point  has a continuous self-map with no fixed points.
7. The same, but for the infinite discrete space $\Bbb Z$.

Hint 2: Think about the problem geometrically. Imagine that you drew a graph of a no-fixed-point function. What would it look like?

Comment: @NPD Hint 3: look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4744409

Comment: It's okay if you don't want to engage anymore (I would appreciate it if you could) I am writing this nevertheless. I am also thinking of them like objects on my table so bear with #6/7-

(1/2/3/5) Any open $\epsilon$-ball contains infinite Q's so it is not discrete. But integers are (I can choose $\epsilon$ = 0.5?) (4) Any inverse $f^{-1}(x)$ is still open when x is open/ closed when closed $x \in X$ (6) shift-each-one-to-the-right-permutation when the finite elements are sitting in a circle (7) transfer to the next bed if they are in an infinite bedroom with infinite beds

Comment: I think instead of posting one-line informal arguments that fit in Math SE comments you should try writing out the _complete_ proofs. You should include explicit references back to earlier theorems or definitions when you depend on them. And I think you should do it on paper.  These very abbreviated proofs that other people leave in comments are not real proofs, just sketcjes of how real proofs would go. You are supposed to fill in tbe details yourself.